# In Visual Studio, are there code comments for C++ like there are for C#?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In Visual Studio with C# you can hover over most of the default code and it will give you a pop-up description that tells you what the code is. I recently started learning C++ and am very much missing that helpful pop-up info. There's a pop-up, but it only contains the method signature, none of the other helpful descriptions that says what the thing is for.

All I could find were instructions on how to make my own, but I'm trying to find out if there are any default ones or maybe a tool I can add that will help.

Edit: Here are a couple pictures to explain what I mean. I don't want to make my own tool tips, I'm trying to find out if there's something that will help me understand what a function, field, etc is for while scrolling through them while in Visual Studio.

C# tool tip:

[image: C# tool tip]

C++ tool tip:
[image: C++ tool tip]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could use Visual Assist.

I think this should be what you want:

[image]

Of course, you could also set it yourself.

The way to customize the `document method` text is under `VassistX->Visual Assist Options->Suggestions`, select `Edit VA Snippets`, Language: C++, Type: Refactoring, then go to `Document Method` and customize. The above example is generated by:

[image]

Also, you could meet your needs through [xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-xml-documentation-comments?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @Rökkr Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.

Answer (score -1):

The pop-up is dumb. It shows whatever comment is provided to any given entity (function, variable name, etc.)

Try to prepend any of your functions with a meaningful comment, then hover over the code that calls that function and see for yourself.

Your observation simply means that C# coders do a better job on commenting their code :)